# subprocess called from multiprocess not finishing

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, multiprocessing, subprocess

I've got a set of videos from which I'm trying to pull random frames. There are a lot of videos, so I want to work in parallel, and `ffmpeg` can splice out the frames for me, so here's the important part of the code:

```py
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from multiprocessing import current_process
from subprocess import Popen

vids_dir = 'just a string'
out_dir = 'another string'

def process_each(f):
    temp = 'temp' + str(current_process()._identity[0])
    os.mkdir(temp)

    proc = Popen(['ffmpeg -i ' + vids_dir + '/' + f + ' ' + temp + '/' + f[:-4] + '_%03d.jpg &> /dev/null'], shell=True) # convert to frames
    proc.wait()

    # do stuff

    os.system('rm -rf ' + temp) # clean up


Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(process_each)(f) for f in tqdm(os.listdir(vids_dir)))
```

I can print out the command being passed to `Popen` and execute it in a shell, and it works. I can open a `python3` session and call the command from `Popen` or `subprocess.call` or even `os.system`, and it works. I can even set `n_jobs=1` in my `Parallel`, and it works.

But the moment I actually parallelize this, I find `ffmpeg` doesn't flush its full results to the temporary folders; it only gets the first one or few frames.

What on earth could be going on? `subprocess` and `multiprocessing` should be able to mix this way.